# PySimpleGUI - CalendarButton

Tags: pysimplegui

I am using a CalendarButton to get a date - no big deal. I have set it's location in the initial layout - also no probs.
I am getting the window's location with window_loc =  window.CurrentLocation()

What I want to do is change the location of the popup calendar to stay with the main window when it is dragged around the screen.
I have tried the window.update route but get an error message
Exception has occurred: TypeError
update() got an unexpected keyword argument 'location'
Is it possible to do this??
Any help appreciated

Tried the code supplied in answer & got

Exception has occurred: TypeError
popup_get_date() got an unexpected keyword argument 'relative_location'

Not sure why

Update - solved
using code:

```
elif event == 'Date':
    main_window_location = window.CurrentLocation()
    chosen_mon_day_year = sg.popup_get_date(location=
                          (main_window_location))
    if chosen_mon_day_year:
        window['-IN-'].update(chosen_mon_day_year)
```

I get the popup to be where I want - with the main window.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you get something wrong for the exception about `window.update`

```py
TypeError update() got an unexpected keyword argument 'location'
```

It should like this

```py
AttributeError: 'Window' object has no attribute 'update'
```

There's no method `update` for `sg.Window`, try `window.move` after window finalized.

> move(x, y)
>
> Move the upper left corner of this window to the x,y coordinates provided

To change the location of the popup calendar to stay with the main window, it's better to call `sg.popup_get_date` with option `relative_location` after one button clicked.

- `'<Configure>'` event for the size of the widget changed. On some platforms, it can mean that the location changed.

Demo Code

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [[sg.Input(key='-IN-'), sg.Button('Date')]]
window = sg.Window('Title', layout, finalize=True)
relative_location = (None, None)
left, top = window.current_location()
window.bind('<Configure>', "Configure")

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == 'Configure':
        new_left, new_top = window.current_location()
        relative_location = new_left - left, new_top - top
    elif event == 'Date':
        chosen_mon_day_year = sg.popup_get_date(relative_location=relative_location)
        if chosen_mon_day_year:
            window['-IN-'].update(chosen_mon_day_year)

window.close()
```